# Constant 'spacesLeft' inferred to have type '()', which may be unexpected Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3, xcode8

I am building a Tic Tac Toe game with an AI using Xcode 8 and Swift. Here are the relevant variables I am using that are contributing to the error:

```
var allSpaces: Set<Int> = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
var playerOneMoves = Set<Int>()
var playerTwoMoves = Set<Int>()
var nextMove: Int? = nil
```

Inside a function defining how the AI will play there are these variables:

```
var count = 0

let spacesLeft = allSpaces.subtract(PlayerOneMoves.union(playerTwoMoves))
```

The latter results in the compiler warning:

> Constant 'spacesLeft" inferred to have type '()', which may be unexpected

There is an if statement just below that says:

```
if allSpaces.subtract(playerOneMoves.union(playerTwoMoves)).count > 0 {
nextMove = spacesLeft[spacesLeft.startIndex.advancedBy(Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(spacesLeft.count))))]

}
```

The condition gives the following error:

> Value of tuple type '()' has no member 'count'

The statement gives the following error:

> Type '()' has no subscript members

I am struggling to find a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first warning, `subtract` returns `Void`, so use `subtracting`:

```
let spacesLeft = allSpaces.subtracting(playerOneMoves.union(playerTwoMoves))
```

For the second error, `advancedBy` is deprecated, you may change like this:

```
if spacesLeft.count > 0 {
    nextMove = spacesLeft[spacesLeft.index(spacesLeft.startIndex, offsetBy: Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(spacesLeft.count))))]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`subtract` modifies `Set` in place and doesn't return a value, you want to use `subtracting`

Answer (score 0):

`Set.subtract` is a mutating function, so it modifies the `Set` in place and its return value is `Void`, which is just a type alias for an empty tuple, `()`, hence the warning.

You should call `Set.substracting`, which is the non-mutating version of `subtract` and returns `Set<Set.Element>`.

Answer (score 0):

The `subtract(_:)` function is a mutating function so it will mutate the `Set` your using to call the function.

From [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/set/1781260-subtract):

> `subtract(_:)`
>
> Removes the elements of the given set from this set.

The reason you're getting the errors is because this function returns `Void` which in Swift is a typealias for an empty tuple([from Swift's source code)](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/82d9ec4634b05ff165b79d6e8977c47cc39bf7e0/stdlib/public/core/Policy.swift#L53). Since `Void` has no subscripts nor `count` property/variable you get those errors.

Maybe you should take a look at the `subtracting(_:)` function, which returns a different `Set`.

From [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/set/1783322-subtracting):

> `subtracting(_:)`
>
> Returns a new set containing the elements of this set that do not occur in the given set.